# How to mimic the OneNote button that Outlook for Windows has in Mac

Tags: outlook, applescript, onenote

Is there a way using AppleScripts to create a function that allows from a Outlook meetings to send the relevant meeting info into a oneNote as the Outlook for Windows does?

Comment: Maybe this belongs over on Ask Different?

Answer (score 0):

OneNote Online (in a browser) has a meeting notes button. You could use that one.

Comment: Thank for your info! I 've noticed that, but unfortunately is requesting a User Id and Password. When I try to use my organization credentials, something is not right and instead to show me my organizational single sign on windows, it's sending me back to the previous request credential screen.

Comment: I've tried it again from my office and now is working. I don't know if something is related to the VPN. Anyway. thanks again for your help!